# Wrong output from linear model summary table

Tags: r, tidyverse, linear-regression

Suppose I want to do a linear model regression on the mtcars data set

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

mtcars
linear_model = y~x

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula= linear_model) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(stat(adj.rr.label), stat(eq.label),sep = "*\",    \"*")),
    formula = linear_model, rr.digits = 2, parse = TRUE,size=3)
```

Now I want to summarise the data varaibles obtained in a table - in particular I'm interested in the slope. I have tried the following:

```
table_mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mdl = list(lm(log10(disp) ~ log10(drat), data)), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(adjrsquared = map_dbl(mdl, ~summary(.)$adj.r.squared ),
         mdl = map(mdl, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(mdl)%>%
  filter(term=="log10(drat)")
```

which works fine when data is not log transformed, however when data is log transformed the estimate values in the table are wrong.
Anyone has an idea as to why?

Comment: Keep in mind the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance. If this question isn't about plotting, we don't need the 10 lines of plotting code and can just focus on the issue with calculating the model coefficients, including the difference you're describing between transformed and untransformed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `broom` package and its `tidy` and `glance` functions could be useful here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

dat = mtcars %>% 
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(model = list(lm(log10(disp) ~ log10(drat), data)),
         coefficients = list(tidy(model)),
         statistics = list(glance(model)))

coefficients = dat %>% unnest(coefficients)
statistics = dat %>% unnest(statistics)

coefficients
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl        data model  term  estimate std.error statistic p.value statistics
#>   <dbl> <list<tbl_> <list> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <list>    
#> 1     4   [11 × 10] <lm>   (Int…    2.97      0.524     5.66  3.10e-4 <tibble […
#> 2     4   [11 × 10] <lm>   log1…   -1.57      0.860    -1.83  1.01e-1 <tibble […
#> 3     6    [7 × 10] <lm>   (Int…    2.93      0.206    14.2   3.12e-5 <tibble […
#> 4     6    [7 × 10] <lm>   log1…   -1.22      0.372    -3.28  2.20e-2 <tibble […
#> 5     8   [14 × 10] <lm>   (Int…    2.59      0.255    10.2   3.00e-7 <tibble […
#> 6     8   [14 × 10] <lm>   log1…   -0.102     0.501    -0.203 8.43e-1 <tibble […

statistics
#> # A tibble: 3 x 16
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl      data model coefficients r.squared adj.r.squared  sigma statistic
#>   <dbl> <list<tb> <lis> <list>           <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     4 [11 × 10] <lm>  <tibble [2 …   0.271          0.190  0.102     3.35  
#> 2     6  [7 × 10] <lm>  <tibble [2 …   0.682          0.619  0.0562   10.7   
#> 3     8 [14 × 10] <lm>  <tibble [2 …   0.00341       -0.0796 0.0846    0.0410
#> # … with 8 more variables: p.value <dbl>, df <dbl>, logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>,
#> #   BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

Slope only:

```r
coefficients %>% 
  filter(term == "log10(drat)") %>%
  select(cyl, term, estimate, p.value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl term        estimate p.value
#>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     4 log10(drat)   -1.57   0.101 
#> 2     6 log10(drat)   -1.22   0.0220
#> 3     8 log10(drat)   -0.102  0.843
```

Edit: with respect to your comments, I now see that your two code chunks are doing something different. In your `ggplot2`, you estimate a linear model and then change the axis of your plot. In the second part, you log the variable then estimate a linear model. The first is a purely linear model and you just change the graphical representation. The second is a "lin-log model".

Hopefully this graph will help you see the difference:

```
dat <- mtcars

mod_lin <- lm(mpg ~ hp, dat)
mod_log <- lm(mpg ~ log10(hp), dat)
dat$pred_lin <- predict(mod_lin)
dat$pred_log <- predict(mod_log)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
with(dat, plot(hp, pred_lin,
     main="lin model; lin axis"))
with(dat, plot(hp, pred_lin, log="x",
     main="lin model; log axis"))
with(dat, plot(hp, pred_log,
     main="log model; lin axis"))
with(dat, plot(hp, pred_log, log="x",
     main="log model; log axis"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Vincent! Your code actually gave the same result as mine, however you solution was more elegant. I did express my question quite poorly, but the problem is that the estimates (slope values) from the table (-1.57, -1.22, -0.10) does not match the slope value I get from the stats in my graph which are: y=0.954 - 0.172x, y=1.81 - 0.56x, y=0.592 - 0.0336x. I'm not sure which slope values are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @Vincent! Let's say I pull the estimate from the LM using your code, but without "log10", e.g.: ```... mutate(model = list(lm(disp ~ drat, data)) ... ``` That gives the following estimates in the coefficient table: -36.79921, -72.55967, -16.77288. If I do the ```ggplot2``` without log transforming I get these formulas: y=4.79 -0.00681x, y=5.33 - 0.00952x, y=3.41 - 0.000506. Should they not be identical?

Comment: The nontransformed ```ggplot2``` would be:                                                    
  ```linear_model = y~x                                                                                    
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula= linear_model) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(stat(adj.rr.label), stat(eq.label),sep = "*\",    \"*")), formula = linear_model, rr.digits = 2, parse = TRUE,size=3)```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `stat_poly_eq` function from the `ggpmisc` package. Notice that if you draw the exact same plot but comment out the `scale_*_continuous` lines, then you'll get different estimates. This is very surprising behavior. Why should changing the scale of the *graphical* representation change the underlying model? My intuition is that this is a bug, but I don't know `ggpmisc` enough to be certain.